# Proof of Kraft-McMillan

Tags: coding-theory

In a recently class,  my professor presented a proof of McMillan's inequality. I've been looking at his proof, but for some reason my brain is not making the necessary connection for the step shown below.

[image]

Where does the part on the right come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $(\sum_i x_i)^n = (\sum_i x_i)\cdots (\sum_i x_i) = (\sum_{i_1} x_{i_1}) \cdots (\sum_{i_n} x_{i_n}) = \sum_{i_1} \cdots \sum_{i_n} x_{i_1} \cdots x_{i_n}$.

Then let $x_i = 2^{-l_i}$.

Comment: Oh, duh! Ha. Thanks so much!!

Comment: You're welcome!